# UWP scrollbar with dates

Tags: uwp

Is it with using standard UWP controls, that the Microsoft Photos app has a "sorted" scrollbar? How is it possible to achieve something like this, using UWP.

I've been looking through all the controls but can't really seem to find what I'm looking for.

[image: The Microsoft Photos UWP app with a scrollbar sorted by date.]

Answer (score 1):

> Is it with using standard UWP controls, that the Microsoft Photos app has a "sorted" scrollbar?

Above control is not standard UWP control, If you want to implement this, you need custom it with [Thumb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.thumb?view=winrt-20348) control just like [Slider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/slider), For Thumb vertical scrolling, please refer UWP basic input [XAMLManipulations](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/main/Samples/BasicInput/cs/4-XAMLManipulations.xaml.cs), and if you do want this overall control, you could also post your requirement with windows feed back hub app or post in WinUI Github [repo](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml).